# prevent rename eth0 to eno1

Tags: networking, system-installation, preseed

I am using `preseeding` to automatically install Ubuntu 16.04 from `tftp`

The installer boots up, but fails at the first step: detect network interface.

When I go into the shell, I see in `dmesg` that `eth0` has been renamed to `eno1`.

Can I prevent this using some preseeding command ?

I want to keep `eth0`, not `eno1`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for Debian.  After some searching, what worked for me was to edit the `pxelinux.cfg/default` file.

I have two lines in the default file as follows:

```
KERNEL debian-installer/amd64/linux
APPEND initrd=debian-installer/amd64/initrd.gz url=http://server/preseed.txt interface=eth0 auto=true priority=critical net.ifnames=0
```

What got it working was adding

```
net.ifnames=0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about preseeding with tftp, but generally speaking if you're modifying the OS, to prevent kernel default network device names from being renamed add `net.ifnames=0` to your `/etc/default/kernel` at this line:

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=default
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="iommu=1 intel_iommu=on vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 cgroup_no_v1=all"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
```

On uefi system, run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/grub/grub.cfg` or just `update-grub` if your distro has it (I think Ubuntu does but Debian doesn't, if I remember correctly...) reboot, and voila - kernel net dev names.

Note: You might have to configure software like `NetworkManager` with the new device names, since they'll have different names after reboot.

I'd recommend keeping a copy of your `ip link show` output before rebooting.  E.g.:

```
$ ip link show | sed -n '3~2p' | cut -b 2- | cut -d ':' -f 2 > netdev-names-orig.txt
```

Which gave me:

```
$ cat netdev-names-orig.txt 
 eno1
 wlp111s0
 br0
 lxdbr0
 vethf72710d3@if6
```

For more info on the network device renaming convention, see Debian wiki:  https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames